# SQL Server 2008 R2: Select output of stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to do a select using a stored procedure as a function - it MUST be a stored procedure because it modifies data, and a function cannot do that.

So normally my function is executed like this

```
DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @NextVal int
EXECUTE @RC = dbo.NextPickListNo
@NextVal OUTPUT
```

...but I need it used something like this:

```
select orderID, dbo.NextPickListNo  -- this does not work 
from blah where blah
```

...in other words, like a function.

I am doing this within another stored procedure, so I can use a cursor, if needed - that just seems like a lot of hassle for something this small that ought to be workable in standard T-SQL.

Comment: If it **must be** a stored procedure, then you **CANNOT** use it like a function. Period.

Comment: That is unacceptable.  I don't care how it gets used. I need the values from the proc stuffed into a table.  Values from a stored proc cannot just be banned from appearing in a table or in a result set.  There must be a way or stored procedures are useless.  Personally I think it's stupid to limit functions from updating database tables.  Yes, it's dangerous practice, but I'm a good coder and it's no more dangerous than allowing us to use DROP DATABASE.

Comment: Well, you see - what you're describing is **exactly** the use case for a **function**. If you **insist** on using the **wrong tool** for the job - well, then things are not pleasant. You *can* store the output of a stored procedure into a temporary table and then join against that table - but you just **CANNOT** have a stored procedure return a result set into a `SELECT` list of columns - it's the **WRONG TOOL** for that job.

Comment: This is like "I want my car to go on water" ... "Your car is not designed to go on water.. you need a boat"... "That's unacceptable!"

Comment: Why can't you just use sp to return the result set? If you describe a bit more on the end goal you're trying to accomplish.. I'm sure there's a solution. in other words... i'm sure there's a right boat out there for ya!

Comment: The reasons functions aren't allowed to have side effects is because functions are defined as "procedures without side effects".  If you *really* want to aim this gun at your foot, write a CLR function. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx  It lets you play with the safeties off.

Comment: Ok, let me back up.  I need the result of a stored procedure that modifies data (hence cannot be a function) to be dropped into a column in a data table.  I'd like to do this once per row in my result set.  I don't care what mechanism is used.  And this is not a stupid request, my app requires it.  I'd just rather not have to do this all in the client.  I have found a way to do this, but not as cleanly as I'd like.  http://vstudiojourney.blogspot.com/2013/12/selecting-scalar-values-from-stored.html

Comment: Make your stored procedure return the result as a row set (as @samyi has suggested), that way you'll be able to do `INSERT ... EXECUTE` (and later process the obtained results the way you like by using the table in queries normally). Currently it produces one value, so teach it to return more than one (in your example it has no parameters, so introduce one and let the SP process it accordingly so as to return a set of values). If you elaborate on what specifically the procedure is doing, you may get a more specific suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need functions with side effects, CLR is the way to go.

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [MyCLRLibrary]
FROM '\\Path\To\My\Compiled\CLR'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[NextPickListNo]
RETURNS int WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [MyCLRLibrary].[MyClass].[NextPickListNo]
GO
```